How to read ODB Data in android auto apps?
i'm currently working on an App that needs access to Car Data like: Energy Level, mileage.

The Android Auto Library has APIs that can be used to access car properties and sensors, but i am not sure if i can directly access the Data or i need an OBD Dongle.


You can use the library to read the data directly without an OBD dongle, but, as noted in the documentation, there's no guarantee that it would be reported from the car to Android Auto.

Thank you for the reply. What about using Android Automotive? And if i decide to use an ODB Dongle, is it hard to implement the iterface to communicate with the Dongle? And do all Dongles use the same APIs?
